# How to provide additional parameter to Mapper's Map method?

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper, mapper

I'm trying to map one list to another, but not everything I want is in the source object. Let me explain:

These are my two objects:

```
public class SourceItem
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class TargetItem
{
    public int TargetId { get; set;}
    public string TargetName { get; set;}
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I configure my Mapper:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SourceItem, TargetItem>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TargetId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TargetName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
    }
}
```

When I do this...

```
var targets = Mapper.Map<List<SourceItem>, List<TargetItem>>(sourceItems);
```

...the `targets` list's objects will have `Foo` set to 0. Obviously. What I'm trying to do is to also initialize `Foo` (with the parameter). Like this:

```
fooParameter = 321;

List<TargetItem> targets = Mapper.Map<List<SourceItem>, List<TargetItem>>(sourceItems);
foreach(var target in targets)
{
    target.Foo = fooParameter;
}
```

**Is it possible, to do it using `Mapper`?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Answer (score -1):

You can't do exactly what you want, but you can get pretty close by specifying mapping options when you call Map.

```
fooParameter = 321;

var targets = Mapper.Map<List<SourceItem>, List<TargetItem>>(sourceItems, opt =>
            opt.AfterMap(
                (src, dest) => {
                    foreach (var d in dest)
                    {
                        d.Foo = fooParameter;
                    }
                })
            );
```